# Taking certain information from excel and saving in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need help

I am trying to extra information from one work book and save it in a new one- but I need to separate it depending on the reference it has.

I used the following code which is great but its to a sheet not a new one.

not great with VB- as I used this one a while back.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rangeToSearch As Range
    Set rangeToSearch = Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim searchAmount As String
    searchAmount = InputBox("reference:")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rangeToSearch
        If cell = CLng(searchAmount) Then
            Sheets(1).Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).Copy
            Sheets(2).Rows( _
             Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & _
             ":" & _
             Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 _
             ).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This has worked great so far I just don't know how to change it to a new workbook instead of a sheet.

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1 : Saves the sheet as a new workbook

After the `For-Loop`, add the following :

```
Sheets(2).Copy
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
wb2.SaveAs "C:\Users\YourUser\Documentstest.xls"l
```

And since you used `Option Explicit`, you need to add `dim wb2 as Workbook`at the top of your function

---

Solution #2 : Creates a new workbook to work with

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)

    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)

    Dim rangeToSearch As Range
    Set rangeToSearch = ws1.Range("C2:C" & ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim searchAmount As String
    searchAmount = InputBox("reference:")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rangeToSearch
        If cell = CLng(searchAmount) Then
            ws1.Rows(cell.Row).Copy
            ws2.Rows(ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! However the original task copy all the data with the 'reference' do not copy anymore it only copies the first row.

Comment: Yeah, after writing out that solution I figured it might not be adequate to your need. I'll provide you with what you need as soon as I get to work (I got to leave now)

Comment: Will I need to use a completely different one? thanks

Comment: Great. Perfect for what I want to do! Thanks so much

Comment: If your question is answered, I'd very much appreciate if you'd mark it as so :D